# Show that there is $x \in S^1$ s.t. $f(x)=f(-x)$ for $f \in C^0(S^1, \mathbb{R})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

> Let $f: S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on the unit circle $S^1$.
>
> Show that there is $x \in S^1$ s.t. $f(x)=f(-x)$

Intuitively this is quite clear since I can imagine if this does not hold, we should have sort of a spiral that is not continuous at one point. But I'm not sure how to show this exactly. Any ideas?

Comment: Use the intermediate value theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :**

The function $g :[0,\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$g(t)=f(e^{it})-f(-e^{it})$$

is continuous and satisfies $g(0)=-g(\pi)$. Then apply IVT to $g$.

Comment: Thanks, got it.
Could you explain how you got the intuition to check $0,\pi$ in particular? I also defined the same $g$ but didn't notice this.

Comment: @paxtibimarce Actually you can check any point that are opposite on the circle ! The fact is that the function $h : x \mapsto f(x)-f(-x)$ satisfies $h(x)=-h(-x)$ for every $x \in \mathcal{S}^1$.